# Express with Azure cosmos DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb

Working with express(nodejs), mongoose, and Azure Cosmos DB to return objects.
When I connect to my local mongodb, the following code correctly returns a list of commit objects that exist in local mongodb.

```
Commit
  .find({}, function(err, commits) {
    if (err) {
      res.render('search/index', {});
    } else {
      res.json(commits);
    }
  });
```

However, when connecting to Azure Cosmos DB using a PRIMARY CONNECTION STRING shown on my Azure portal website, the code just returns an empty list.
I checked that the `mongoose.connection.readyState` value is 1.
In addition, I can connect to the Azure Cosmos DB using [Robo 3T](https://robomongo.org/).

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is?

Comment: My problem is that the `find` method just returns an empty list when connecting to Azure Cosmos DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could solve this problem by myself.

**The latest version (v3.1.1) of the library doesn't work for connecting to Azure Cosmos DB.**
You should use mongodb 2.2.33.

I found the solution from a comment on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-samples.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose was designed to work with MongoDB. If your local testing with a real MongoDB server yields the expected result, then the fault is unlikely to be in mongoose or your code. Since CosmosDB only attempts to mimic MongoDB's API, there is no guarantee that it will work the same way. In your case, apparently it doesn't.

Being able to connect to CosmosDB using tools designed to work with MongoDB doesn't necessarily mean that CosmosDB will return the correct result.

If you require a cloud-based MongoDB deployment, using [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) is likely the best solution at this point in time.